# Appending text to existing file without overwriting it

Tags: java, nio

I'm adding some content into an existing file `NameList.txt`, which already contains some text there.

But when I run the program, it removes all the existing content before starting to write new ones.

**Note:** I also try to find where is the file ending line. E.g. by using `while ((lines = reader.readLine()) == null)`, where the `lines` variable is of the type `String`.

```java
public class AddBooks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path Source = Paths.get("NameList.txt");

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("Us-ASCII");
        try (
            BufferedWriter write = Files.newBufferedWriter(Source, charset);
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Source, charset);
        ) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s;
            String line;
            int i = 0, isEndOfLine;

            do {
                System.out.println("Book Code");
                s = input.nextLine();
                write.append(s, 0, s.length());
                write.append("\t \t");

                System.out.println("Book Title");
                s = input.nextLine();
                write.append(s, 0, s.length());
                write.append("\t \t");

                System.out.println("Book Publisher");
                s = input.nextLine();
                write.append(s, 0, s.length());
                write.newLine();

                System.out.println("Enter more Books? y/n");
                s = input.nextLine();

            } while(s.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

My only requirement is to add new content to existing file.

Comment: In the do block, put write.flush();

Comment: same Problem overwriting

Comment: Hi, your question was is the new "Help and Improvement" review queue and I just edited it. I am required to give you a feedback, so I will tell you to pay attention to code formatting, where every line of code is required to be prefixed by at least 4 spaces to be recognized as code. Also, I removed some excessive blank lines in your code and added a few spaces to make it more readable. And sorry to tell you, but your English was really bad, try to improve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this!

```
BufferedWriter write = Files.newBufferedWriter(Source, charset, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

And see this!
[StandardOpenOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)

2nd..

```
 while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
```

Appendix.. insert

```
writer.close();
```

before

```
} while(s.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```